# XSLT read external XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file containing paths to other XML files, example:

```
<PATH>InsertPathHere</PATH>
<PATH>InsertPathHere</PATH>
```

Is there a way to "open" the XML files and use their data using XSLT?
I want to take the data in the seperate files and use them with XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an XML file like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <PATH>InsertPath1Here.xml</PATH>
  <PATH>InsertPath2Here.xml</PATH>
</root>
```

and secondary XML files like `InsertPath1Here.xml`

```
<data>
    <value name="Value1">ABC</value>
</data>
```

and `InsertPath2Here.xml`

```
<data>
    <value name="Value2">DEF</value>
</data>
```

you can use an XSLT file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="document(PATH)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="data" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which creates the (correct) output:

```
<data>
    <value name="Value1">ABC</value>
</data>
<data>
    <value name="Value2">DEF</value>
</data>
```